# How do I access API endpoint on same network but different machine from Android Emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a machine that's running a test backend service (machine 1) and a separate machine (machine 2) running the Android emulator. When I input the endpoint from machine 1 in machine 2's ***browser*** the results show up. However, when I input the address to fetch the API endpoint in machine 2's ***Android Studio emulator***, the results don't go through. How can I make it so that the emulator can read the endpoint located on machine 2? Thanks. 
I know the solution if the backend is located on the same machine but I can't find anything if they are separate. Running a Mac

tl;dr:

backend located on different machine (machine 1)

> String url = "192.xxx.x.xxx:3000";

good in different machine's(machine 2) broswer but not in Android Emulator(also machine 2). How do I let emulator accept this? Running Mac. Thanks

Comment: Could be a firewall issue. Check your settings on your Mac and routers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone comes across this in the future, I used ngrok.com. It connects your localhost to the web and from there you can access your API endpoints. It's really easy to set up too so I recommend it for testing